# Do I need a migration for EF code first when the database does not exist in SQL Azure?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I have tried lots of variations of EF migration v6.0.1 (from no database, to empty databases to existing databases) and I have a particular problem with **Azure** DB instances not being able to correctly be created on first deploy using Octopus deploy.

There are a number of places where this could be going wrong, so I thought I would check some basics of EF Code First migration with you fine people if I may:

If I create a code-first model, and know that the database **does not exist** in the intended target database server on Azure. With the default of 'CreateDatabaseIfNotExists' approach **and** with AutomaticMigrations disabled;

If I then call 'migrate.exe' with the assembly containing my DbContext and migration Configuration will I get a new database created with the current state of the model? or will I get a new database with nothing in it? i.e. do I need to explicitly 'add-migration' for the initial state of the model?

I have read in the documentation that the database instance should be created automatically by the migration process, but no one states clearly (at least to me) that this newly created database will be generated with the current model without a formal 'initial state' migration created.

So the question is this: do I need an explicit migration model generated for migrate.exe to work from?

Through whatever means I try, I get a database but the application launches with the unfriendly message "Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations." Remembering that this is the same application library that just created the database in the first place (from scratch) I fail to understand how this has happened!

I did manually delete the target database a few times via SQL Server management studio, is this bad? Have I removed some vital user account that I need to recover?

Comment: I apologize for the wall of text, but I hope that my answer gives you a bit more insight into what is actually happening.

Comment: No apology necessary here, it's a great wall of text, I'm just reading it through. I have a couple of questions which I will append to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations and the Database Initializer `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` **are not the same**.

Migrations uses the Database Initializer `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, which relies upon a special table in the database `_MigrationsHistory`.

By contrast, `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` is one of the Database Initializers which relies upon the special database table `EdmMetadata`.  It does exactly as it implies:  Creates a database with tables matching the current state of the model, i.e. a table for each `DbSet<T>`, ***only when the database does not exist***.

The specific error you have quoted here, `Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata.`, occurs due to the existence of `DbSet<T>` objects which were added to the code base *after* the initial database creation, and do not exist in `EdmMetadata`.

There are 4 basic Database Initializers available, 3 of which are for use when migrations is not being used:

- `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`
- `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges`
- `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`

Also note, the 4th Initializer, `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, will allow you to use Migrations *even if* `AutomaticMigrations` is disabled;  `AutomaticMigrations` serves a diffierent purpose, and does not interact with the Database Initializers directly.

If you intend to use Migrations, you should change the Database Initializer to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` and forget about the other 3.  If, instead, you intend to *not* use Migrations, then the choice of Initializer is situational.

- `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` will be more appropriate when you are certain that your data model is not undergoing active change, and you only intend to be concerned with database creation on a new deployment.  This Initializer will elp ensure that you do not have any issues with accidental deletion of a database or live data.
- `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges` is most appropriate in development, when you are changing the model fairly often, and want to be able to verify these changes to the model.  It would not be appropriate for a production server, as changes to the model could inadvertently cause the database to be recreated.
- `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` is only appropriate in testing, where your database is created from scratch every time you run your tests.

Migrations differs from these 3 Database Initializers, in that it never *drops the* ***database***, it instead uses Data Motion to execute a series of `Create Table` and `Drop Table` SQL calls.

You also can use `Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0` in the Package Manager Console at any time, no matter which Database Initializer you are using, to generate a full SQL script that can be run against a server to recreate the database.

Comment: Claies, this is a great answer and I absolutely did not know about the EdmMetadata table. I understand that the migrations versus creation are different things now, I assumed that the creation mechanism was just the first step of the migration approach. To me it seemed sensible to opt for the 'create database if it doesn't exist' approach. Let me alter my code to use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion now and see what happens and I'll report back!

Comment: OK, so I've switched to using the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion (which I set in a static constructor of my DbContext, is this ok?). I had to create a migration for the initial state of the model. I then ran migrate.exe which created the database. I have a single __MigrationHistory record which is my initial model. On application startup I still get the same error. Must be something subtle I've missed.

Comment: do you happen to have an extra connection string in your web.config? something that starts with `metadata=res ...`?  These aren't actually necessary with migrations, and if they are present in the web.config but pointing to the local test db, they may not be updated automatically in azure the way that the actual db connection string is.

Comment: Good though, but no sign of any metadata's in my config files. I'll keep digging!

Comment: `EdmMetadata` is actually obsolete;  it was a simple way of determining if the Code First model had been changed since the database was created. However, it couldn’t be used to determine *how* the model used to create the database was different from the current model. This didn’t matter too much since there was no way to migrate the database from one version to the next. (The entire database was just dropped and recreated).  Migrations can actually detect the order that tables should be created and deleted; if you are getting this error, perhaps the `_MigrationHistory` table is at fault?

Comment: I think you might be right that the MigrationHistory table is at fault. I've just started reading this article: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/inside_of_ef_migrations/ which is pointing some fingers potentially at a mismatched local db (which I'm generating migrations from) or perhaps that Azure databases don't have the 4 part naming structure, but I'm guessing at the moment.

Comment: Well, ultimately your answer led to me finding out that there were a combination of errors that led to this message. So, I think it only fair that you get my accepted answer and up-vote. I shall fill out a bit more detail in a separate answer alongside. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, many thanks to Claies who helped me get to the bottom of this problem. I have accepted his answer as correct as ultimately it was a combination of his response and a few additional bits of reading that got me to my solution.

In answer to the actual posts question 'Do I need a migration for EF code first when the database does not exist in SQL Azure?' the answer is yes you do if you have disabled automatic migrations. But there is a little more to be aware of:

The Azure aspects of this particular problem are actually irrelevant in my situation. My problem was two-fold:

1. The migration being generated was out of sync with respect to the target model. What do I mean? I mean, that I was generating the migration script from my local database which itself was not in sync with the local codebase which created a migration that was incorrect. This can be seen by comparing the first few lines of the Model text in the __MigrationHistory. This awareness was helped by referring to this helpful [post](http://blog.randomdust.com/2015/07/entity-framework-code-first-deployment-of-azure-ad-sample/) which explains how it works.
2. And more embarrassingly (I'm sure we've all done it) is that my octopus deployment of the web site itself (using Octopack) somehow neglected to include the Web.Config file. From what I can tell, this may have occurred after I installed a transform extension to Visual Studio. Within my nuget package I can see that there is a web.config.transform file but not a web.config. Basically this meant that when the application started up, it had no configuration file to turn to, no connections string at all. But this resulted in the slightly misleading error

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not
>   contain model metadata.

Whereas what it should have said was, there isn't a connection string you idiot.
Hopefully this helps people understand the process a little better after reading Claies answer and also that blog-post. First though, check you have a web.config file and that it has a connection string in it...